# Pine script - request.security

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Request.security shows different results for accounts with Real time datas purchased and without Real time datas(i.e. free account). Is there anyone knowing what is the reason for this?

The following is the pine script as reference.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/    
// © cocococotsoi

//@version=5    
indicator("%K CU SMA RSI_0319")    
swr = input(true, title='RSI')
lenRSI = input.int(14, minval=1, title='Length RSI')    
srs = input.int(50, minval=1, title='Length sma RSI')

src=close    
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), lenRSI)    
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), lenRSI)    
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)    
mr = ta.sma(rsi, srs)    
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)    
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)    
periodD = input.int(14, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)    
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)    
customFunc()=\> ta.crossover(k, mr)

s1686=request.security('1686', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1691=request.security('1691', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1717=request.security('1717', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1735=request.security('1735', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1755=request.security('1755', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1766=request.security('1766', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1772=request.security('1772', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1776=request.security('1776', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1787=request.security('1787', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1788=request.security('1788', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1789=request.security('1789', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1798=request.security('1798', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1799=request.security('1799', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1800=request.security('1800', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1801=request.security('1801', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1810=request.security('1810', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1811=request.security('1811', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1812=request.security('1812', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1813=request.security('1813', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1816=request.security('1816', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1818=request.security('1818', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1821=request.security('1821', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1833=request.security('1833', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1858=request.security('1858', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1866=request.security('1866', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1873=request.security('1873', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1876=request.security('1876', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1877=request.security('1877', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1882=request.security('1882', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1883=request.security('1883', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1888=request.security('1888', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1896=request.security('1896', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1898=request.security('1898', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1907=request.security('1907', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1910=request.security('1910', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1911=request.security('1911', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1913=request.security('1913', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1918=request.security('1918', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1919=request.security('1919', timeframe.period, customFunc())    
s1928=request.security('1928', timeframe.period, customFunc())

scr_label='%KCusmaRSI:  '    
scr_label :=s1686? scr_label + '1686\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1691? scr_label + '1691\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1717? scr_label + '1717\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1735? scr_label + '1735\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1755? scr_label + '1755\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1766? scr_label + '1766\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1772? scr_label + '1772\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1776? scr_label + '1776\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1787? scr_label + '1787\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1788? scr_label + '1788\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1789? scr_label + '1789\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1798? scr_label + '1798\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1799? scr_label + '1799\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1800? scr_label + '1800\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1801? scr_label + '1801\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1810? scr_label + '1810\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1811? scr_label + '1811\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1812? scr_label + '1812\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1813? scr_label + '1813\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1816? scr_label + '1816\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1818? scr_label + '1818\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1821? scr_label + '1821\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1833? scr_label + '1833\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1858? scr_label + '1858\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1866? scr_label + '1866\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1873? scr_label + '1873\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1876? scr_label + '1876\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1877? scr_label + '1877\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1882? scr_label + '1882\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1883? scr_label + '1883\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1888? scr_label + '1888\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1896? scr_label + '1896\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1898? scr_label + '1898\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1907? scr_label + '1907\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1910? scr_label + '1910\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1911? scr_label + '1911\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1913? scr_label + '1913\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1918? scr_label + '1918\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1919? scr_label + '1919\\n' : scr_label    
scr_label :=s1928? scr_label + '1928\\n' : scr_label

lab_1= label.new(bar_index, 0, scr_label ,color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, style = label.style_label_down, yloc = yloc.price)

label.delete(lab_1\[35\])    
c = color.rgb(0,255,0,0)    
plot(0, color=c)
```

Free accounts: results are correct

Real time data accounts: results show both cross, crossup, cross under.